# Traceroute to 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, routing

out of curiosity, I decided to traceroute the IP 0.0.0.0 using `mtr`. This is the result:

`mtr --report -c 30 0.0.0.0`

```
HOST: max-laptop                  Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- localhost                  0.0%    30    0.2   0.1   0.0   0.2   0.0
  2.|-- localhost                  0.0%    29    0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0
  3.|-- localhost                  0.0%    28    0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0
  4.|-- localhost                  0.0%    27    0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0
  5.|-- localhost                  0.0%    26    0.1   0.1   0.0   0.1   0.0
  ....
 28.|-- localhost                  0.0%     3    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
 29.|-- localhost                  0.0%     2    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
 30.|-- localhost                  0.0%     1    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
```

where the stations 6-27 are `localhost`, too. How come that a request is routed through a host multiple times?

Comment: Various clients will treat it differently, but 0.0.0.0 is a special non-routable address: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0. Out of curiosity, what is the OS/distro/version you ran this from?

Comment: @MaQleod: Hello, I am using `mtr` shipped with Ubuntu 13.10, version 0.85!